# Domain not propagating

Tags: dns, propagation

I have a domain - saghtar.org.mt - that is failing to propagate to my Bluehost VPS account (waited for over a week in one instance). Today I tried an experiment and pointed nameservers towards another hosting account. It propagated very quickly (within 1 or 2 hours). Bluehost chat agents have no clue what's wrong. Is there anything one can do to diagnose such a problem or does one have to give up and choose another hosting provider in such situations?

Comment: There is no propagation in the DNS but anyway your questions if offtopic here as not related to programming. Have a look at [sf], [su] or [webmaster.se] depending on the exact question. There are online tools, see https://dnsviz.net/d/saghtar.org.mt/dnssec/ which shows your domain is currently very broken in its DNS configuration (lame delegation)

Comment: Some registries will refuse name servers that do not comply with certain technical requirements, for example at least two different name servers on different subnets, or must accept TCP connections etc. The Maltese registry doesn't seem to list any specific requirements though. What were the NS you tried ?